# JRuby Rails3 Trinidad/Jetty_Rails fails on simplest install - feeling as dim as a 2watt bulb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jetty, jruby, trinidad-gem

Ok. Been getting quite frustrated trying to get JRuby/Rails3 running with jetty and tomcat.
Trying to get a local install of jruby/rails3 and jetty/tomcat app running on OS-X.
(And eventually to an Ubuntu stage and live server)
The error I always get on startup is

```
Could not find activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

I've tried googling myself to distraction trying to find out why this happens. One source mentioned an issue with 'bundler' but didn't give any version information. Most others gave varying options to change the Gemfile which I have tried exhaustively for the last 5 hours with no luck.

In exasperation I decided to start from scratch with a plain install.

Installed jruby in /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/ with symlink for /opt/jruby.
Gems installed:

```
jruby -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
ActiveRecord-JDBC (0.5)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.1.1)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.1.1)
activeresource (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
arel (2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.6)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0145.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
daemon_controller (0.2.5)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
htmlentities (4.2.4)
i18n (0.5.0)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
jetty-rails (0.8.1)
jruby-jars (1.5.6)
jruby-openssl (0.7.3)
jruby-rack (1.0.5)
mail (2.2.15, 2.2.12)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5 java)
nokogiri (1.4.1 java)
passenger (3.0.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7, 0.5.6)
rails (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
ruby-mp3info (0.6.13)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sources (0.0.1)
spruz (0.2.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
trinidad (1.0.5)
trinidad_jars (1.0.0)
tzinfo (0.3.24, 0.3.23)
warbler (1.2.1)
```

As you can see I have installed quite a few gems to get this working. Sigh... Might be the ActiveRecord-JDBC?

Anyway, go to dev folder:

```
cd ~/dev_folder
jruby -S rails new test_app --database mysql --template http://jruby.org
...the normal create/apply/gsub output...
cd test_app
bundle install
...normal bundle output...
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using jdbc-mysql (5.1.13) 
...rest of bundle output...
```

Now start trinidad for example:

```
jruby -S trinidad
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-3000"]
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig
INFO: No global web.xml found
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: using runtime pool timeout of 30 seconds
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received min runtimes = 1
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received max runtimes = 5
Could not find activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
Exception in thread "JRuby-Rack-App-Init-0" org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: aborted
Feb 9, 2011 1:36:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-3000"]
^C
```

Or jetty_rails:

```
jruby -S jetty_rails
2011-02-09 13:44:10.122::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
Starting server 3000
2011-02-09 13:44:10.272::INFO:  jetty-6.1.14
2011-02-09 13:44:11.045:/:INFO:  Info: using runtime pool timeout of 30 seconds
2011-02-09 13:44:11.045:/:INFO:  Info: received min runtimes = 1
2011-02-09 13:44:11.045:/:INFO:  Info: received max runtimes = 5
Could not find activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
Exception in thread "JRuby-Rack-App-Init-0" org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: aborted
^C
```

I'm going to re-install jruby in a new folder and install the absolute minimum gems and try the same thing again.

In the meantime, if anyone has a clue as to why this would be happening please post, as I'm sure I'm not alone on this one...

Kimbo.

Ah. Hmm. Ok. Here's a transcript for a complete "from-bare-metal" install.

I archived my previous jruby install and re-unpacked it from the tarball, then:

```
jruby -S gem install rails
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
Fetching: activesupport-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-2.1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: i18n-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.5.7.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-mount-0.6.13.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.24.gem (100%)
Fetching: abstract-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: erubis-2.6.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: arel-2.0.8.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: mime-types-1.16.gem (100%)
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: treetop-1.4.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.2.15.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: thor-0.14.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: railties-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: bundler-1.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: rails-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.4
Successfully installed builder-2.1.2
Successfully installed i18n-0.5.0
Successfully installed activemodel-3.0.4
Successfully installed rack-1.2.1
Successfully installed rack-test-0.5.7
Successfully installed rack-mount-0.6.13
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.24
Successfully installed abstract-1.0.0
Successfully installed erubis-2.6.6
Successfully installed actionpack-3.0.4
Successfully installed arel-2.0.8
Successfully installed activerecord-3.0.4
Successfully installed activeresource-3.0.4
Successfully installed mime-types-1.16
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.1
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.9
Successfully installed mail-2.2.15
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.0.4
Successfully installed thor-0.14.6
Successfully installed railties-3.0.4
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.10
Successfully installed rails-3.0.4
23 gems installed
```

Install the other gems:

```
jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
Fetching: bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0145.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: jruby-openssl-0.7.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0145.2
Successfully installed jruby-openssl-0.7.3
2 gems installed

jruby -S gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter 
Fetching: activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1
1 gem installed

jruby -S gem install trinidad
Fetching: trinidad_jars-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: jruby-rack-1.0.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: trinidad-1.0.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed trinidad_jars-1.0.0
Successfully installed jruby-rack-1.0.5
Successfully installed trinidad-1.0.5
3 gems installed

jruby -S gem install jetty-rails
Fetching: jetty-rails-0.8.1.gem (100%)
PostInstall.txt
Successfully installed jetty-rails-0.8.1
1 gem installed

jruby -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.0.4)
activerecord (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.1.1)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.1.1)
activeresource (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
arel (2.0.8)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0145.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
jetty-rails (0.8.1)
jruby-openssl (0.7.3)
jruby-rack (1.0.5)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
nokogiri (1.4.1 java)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.4, 2.3.5)
railties (3.0.4)
rake (0.8.7)
ruby-mp3info (0.6.13)
sources (0.0.1)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
trinidad (1.0.5)
trinidad_jars (1.0.0)
tzinfo (0.3.24)

jruby -S rails new TestApp --database=mysql --template http://jruby.org
create  
create  README
...
blah blah...
...
create  vendor/plugins
create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
apply  http://jruby.org
apply    http://jruby.org/templates/default.rb
gsub      Gemfile
gsub      config/database.yml

cd TestApp
cat Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

platforms :ruby do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'jdbc-mysql', :require => false
end
...blah blah...

cat config/database.yml 
...elided...
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: TestApp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
...elided...

bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.4) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.4) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.4) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.4) 
Using arel (2.0.8) 
Using activerecord (3.0.4) 
Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.0.4) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using jdbc-mysql (5.1.13) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.4) 
Using rails (3.0.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Now create databases:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE TestApp_development DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE TestApp_test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE TestApp_production DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Test with WEBrick:

```
jruby -S rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-02-09 14:40:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-02-09 14:40:40] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-01-10) [java]
[2011-02-09 14:40:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=25549 port=3000
Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 at Wed Feb 09 14:40:43 +1000 2011
SQL (3.0ms)  SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as 
Rendered inline template (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Browse to http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties

```
Ruby version    1.8.7 (java)
RubyGems version    1.4.2
Rack version    1.2
Rails version   3.0.4
Active Record version   3.0.4
Action Pack version 3.0.4
Active Resource version 3.0.4
Action Mailer version   3.0.4
Active Support version  3.0.4
Middleware  
ActionDispatch::Static
Rack::Lock
ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache
Rack::Runtime
Rails::Rack::Logger
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
Rack::Sendfile
ActionDispatch::Callbacks
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
ActiveRecord::QueryCache
ActionDispatch::Cookies
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
ActionDispatch::Flash
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
Rack::MethodOverride
ActionDispatch::Head
ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
Application root    /Users/kim/Projects/TestApp
Environment development
Database adapter    mysql
Database schema version 0
```

Try trinidad:

```
jruby -S trinidad
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-3000"]
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig
INFO: No global web.xml found
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: using runtime pool timeout of 30 seconds
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received min runtimes = 1
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received max runtimes = 5
Could not find jdbc-mysql-5.1.13 in any of the sources
Feb 9, 2011 2:42:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error: unable to initialize application
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: exit
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:838:in `exit'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1041:in `require'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:34:in `require'
from /Users/kim/RubymineProjects/TestApp/config/boot.rb:6:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1041:in `require'
from /Users/kim/RubymineProjects/TestApp/config/boot.rb:165:in `load_environment'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jruby-rack-1.0.5/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.5.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:173:in `to_app'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jruby-rack-1.0.5/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.5.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:194:in `new'
from <web.xml>:1:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyObject.java:1204:in `instance_eval'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jruby-rack-1.0.5/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.5.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from <web.xml>:1:in `(root)'
at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:198)
at org.jruby.rack.PoolingRackApplicationFactory$1.run(PoolingRackApplicationFactory.java:160)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit
```

Whoops. Missed jdbc-mysql:

```
jruby -S gem install jdbc-mysql
Successfully installed jdbc-mysql-5.1.13
1 gem installed

jruby -S trinidad
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-3000"]
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig
INFO: No global web.xml found
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: using runtime pool timeout of 30 seconds
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received min runtimes = 1
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received max runtimes = 5
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: add application to the pool. size now = 1
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-3000"]
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO:
```

Browse to http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties and all is ok.

```
Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 at Wed Feb 09 14:45:19 +1000 2011
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO:   SQL (4.0ms)  SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO:   Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as 
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Rendered inline template (2.0ms)
Feb 9, 2011 2:45:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

Edit the public index.html and changes are available.

Now try jetty_rails

```
jruby -S jetty_rails
/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:242:in `activate': can't activate activesupport (= 2.3.5, runtime) for [], already activated activesupport-3.0.4 for ["jetty-rails-0.8.1"] (Gem::LoadError)
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:33:in `require'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jetty_rails.rb:10:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1041:in `require'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jetty_rails.rb:29:in `require'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/bin/jetty_rails:37:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066:in `load'
```

The fix is to edit /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jetty_rails.rb:

```
vi /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jetty_rails.rb
```

Change this:

```
require "java"
require "rubygems"
require "activesupport"
require "jetty_rails/jars"
```

To this:

```
require "java"
require "rubygems"
#require "activesupport"
require "active_support"
require "active_support/all"
require "jetty_rails/jars"
```

This should use a rails version if/else but this is a quick fix.

```
jruby -S jetty_rails
2011-02-09 14:49:45.918::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
Starting server 3000
2011-02-09 14:49:46.131::INFO:  jetty-6.1.14
2011-02-09 14:49:46.833:/:INFO:  Info: using runtime pool timeout of 30 seconds
2011-02-09 14:49:46.834:/:INFO:  Info: received min runtimes = 1
2011-02-09 14:49:46.834:/:INFO:  Info: received max runtimes = 5
2011-02-09 14:49:53.122:/:WARN:  Error: unable to initialize application
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: uninitialized constant Rack::Runtime
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `tap'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `default_middleware_stack'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `app'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in `(class Finisher)'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
from /opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /Users/kim/RubymineProjects/TestApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `(root)'
from /Users/kim/RubymineProjects/TestApp/config/environment.rb:26:in `load'
from /Users/kim/RubymineProjects/TestApp/config/environment.rb:26:in `load_environment'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jruby-rack-0.9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:151:in `new'
from <script>:2:in `(root)'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jruby-rack-0.9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
from file:/opt/jruby-1.6.0.RC1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jetty-rails-0.8.1/lib/jruby-rack-0.9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
from <script>:2:in `(root)'
at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:153)
at org.jruby.rack.PoolingRackApplicationFactory$1.run(PoolingRackApplicationFactory.java:157)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant Rack::Runtime
2011-02-09 14:50:17.048::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3000
```

Rats. So close...

Comment: This isn't really a question -- it's more like the journal of an Arctic explorer. Let us know when you reach the North Pole. :)

Comment: Yes, and please add your gemfile when you do so that we get a comprehensive list of stuff that is needed to get it to work

Comment: Working on it. Will post results as soon as I have it.

Comment: Oh. While I think of it. If you get that "Could not find activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1 in any of the sources" error, it's because of an errant gem in your ~/.gem folder. You can check it by doing "bundle show activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.1" to get the exact path. Simply rename or whack the folder and redo the bundle install and it fixes it. I've almost got the whole stack functional including mongo, and will post the recipe as soon as I can.

Comment: For jetty, Nick Sieger suggested using Kirk instead of jetty_rails. Still can't get either functional using 1.6.0RC2 at present.

Comment: cool story brother! How your story ends ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your jruby to the 1.6.0 final?

Comment: Ok. I need to close this I think. I moved onto to 1.6.0 as soon as it was announced - might have been one of the first to snarf it :-) I also am now using trinidad/mongo/mysql all together quite well. I've had to up the Xmx level to make it function at a reasonable speed as I'm dealing with 5 MySQL and 10 Mongo DBs. To describe the system in detail would bloat this already excessive post, so if anyone wants to know the full details, contact me directly at k i m a t p o l y d u c k dot c o dot u k (I'm actually on the Gold Coast in Oz, but I still have an old UK email I use)

Answer (score -1):

Not really a specific answer to your question, but you might want to check out [TorqueBox](http://torquebox.org/) for running Rails apps on JRuby/JBoss. Its very easy to get up and running.